# Prove that in a graph a group of even nodes there are two of degree at least $2$

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

We have just started learning graphs, and I understand the concept clearly, but when it comes to proving something I just don't know how to start!

> Prove that in in a group of an even number of people there are at least two of them that the number of the common people that they know is even.

So I translated it to a Graphs problem:

> Given a graph $G$ (not directed; knowing someone is mutual), prove that in every group of an ***even number*** of vertices there are at least two vertices that the number of their ***common*** neighbors is ***even***

I understand that this is not of the hard questions, but I just can not think the methods of proving such things in Graphs in my head, yet. I would be happy for a direction!

Comment: Do we assume that any vertex is in the neighbourhood of itself (i.e. there is loop at every vertex, i.e. every person knows himself/herself)?

Comment: The question mentions nothing about it, but I would only guess that it is not...

Comment: no. 0 is an even number

Comment: I just drew a graph with 3 vertices in the shape of a baseless triangle. and I took two of them (not the ones that would imply the base,) if we didn't count that a vertex knows itself then the theorem is wrong!

Comment: Again: $0$ is an even number. In the baseless triangle you have 2 vertices that don't have a neighbour in common

Comment: Ah I see, pretty much any two vertices that you take in the graph I mentioned approve with this theory.

Comment: The body treats a completely different problem than the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can find a nice solution here.](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=68109)

Comment: @TheNotMe: The material on this site is for everyone who might find it useful, not just for the original poster. Please don't leave your question in an inconsistent state (see my comment under the question), even after it's been answered; that will make it more difficult for others in the future to benefit from the answer, e.g. by making it more difficult to find it through a search.